# iOS - Create UIView subclass for rounded rectangle

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, storyboard, subclass

I'm trying to create & use a very simple UIView subclass for a rectangle with rounded corners.  I've created a new class as follows :

RoundedRect.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface RoundedRect : UIView
@end
```

RoundedRect.m

```
#import "RoundedRect.h"

@implementation RoundedRect

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [[self layer] setCornerRadius:10.0f];
        [[self layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I'm using iOS 5.1 with storyboards and have set the custom class property in the IB inspector window to 'RoundedRect', but when I run the app the rectangle still has square corners.  Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `initWithFrame` method is not called when the view is instantiated from a XIB file. Instead, the `initWithCoder:` initializer is called, so you need to perform the same initialization in this method.

Comment: I tend to do additional setup in `-awakeFromNib`. Is there any issue with that?

Comment: The difference is that `awakeFromNib` is sent once all the objects have been loaded from the XIB. It may or may not be what is desired, and I suppose in many cases it does not matter at all.

Answer (score 23):

In iOS 5 and up, there is absolutely no need to subclass - you can do it all from Interface Builder.

1. Select the UIView you want to modify.
2. Go to the Identity Inspector.
3. In "User Defined & Runtime Attributes", add "layer.cornerRadius" in Key Path, Type should be "Number" and whatever setting you require.
4. Also add 'layer.masksToBounds' as Boolean.
5. Done! With no subclassing, and all in IB.

Answer (score 18):

The other guys have already answered the question but I would refactor it like this to enable use in nibs and in code

```
#import "RoundedRect.h"

@implementation RoundedRect

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit;
{
    CALayer *layer = self.layer;
    layer.cornerRadius  = 10.0f;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

For views that are loaded from a NIB file, the designated initializer is `initWithCoder:`. `initWithFame:` is not called in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If UIView load from Nib, you should use method

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
```