# UILabel: background dependent color (greenColor and clearColor)

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to make progress bar with the label in it.
Here is what I've done so far.
[image]

Here is code.

```c
//PDProgressView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface PDProgressView : UIView {
    CGFloat _progress;
}
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat progress;
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```c
//PDProgressView.m
#import "PDProgressView.h"

@implementation PDProgressView
@synthesize progress = _progress;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //init
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set up environment.
    CGSize size = [self bounds].size;
    UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    UIColor *foregroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:42.0];

    // Prepare progress as a string.
    NSString *progress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)round([self progress] * 100)];
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [@{ NSFontAttributeName : font } mutableCopy];
    CGSize textSize = [progress sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    CGFloat progressX = ceil([self progress] * size.width);
    CGPoint textPoint = CGPointMake(ceil((size.width - textSize.width) / 2.0), ceil((size.height - textSize.height) / 2.0));

    // Draw background + foreground text
    [backgroundColor setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, [self bounds]);
    attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = foregroundColor;
    [progress drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:attributes];

    // Clip the drawing that follows to the remaining progress' frame.
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGRect remainingProgressRect = CGRectMake(progressX, 0.0, size.width - progressX, size.height);
    CGContextAddRect(context, remainingProgressRect);
    CGContextClip(context);

    // Draw again with inverted colors.
    [foregroundColor setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, [self bounds]);
    attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = backgroundColor;
    [progress drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:attributes];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress {
    _progress = fminf(1.0, fmaxf(progress, 0.0));
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

This codes are from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10190872/10536248).

What I want to do is to make the white to be transparent.

Like this.(I just switched white color to the same color as background color)

[image]

So, I tried changing `foregroundColor` to `clearColor`. But I got a rect filed with `greenColor`.
[image]

What should I do to make white to be transparent like the second image?

Comment: Just as you said. Change the white color to the color of the background.

Comment: @matt I'm going to use this on the image, and some views. So I need it to be transparent.

Comment: Try changing the .tintColor property to what you want it to be